# TypeScript annotated React components with injected properties from react-intl: am I doing this right?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-intl

A project I've been converting to TypeScript makes heavy use of [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl), which has typings available on DefinitelyTyped.

react-intl can be used in a few different ways, but the way it's getting used in this project generally goes like this:

```
// greeter.js module
import {injectIntl} from 'react-intl'

function Greeter ({intl}) {
  <p>{intl.formatMessage({id: 'greetingStringId'})</p>
}

export default injectIntl(Greeter)
```

and that would get used simply like:

```
<Greeter />
```

The problem is, given that I'm converting this project bit by bit, if I don't convert the Greeter module before converting modules which make use of it, TypeScript infers that the `intl` property is mandatory, and because I'm not passing it down directly (but it's instead being injected by `injectIntl`) it complains that the `intl` property isn't there.

So far I've been able to convert these modules first before converting the modules which make use of them (by using the ReactIntl.InjectedIntl type on that property):

```
// greeter.tsx module
import {injectIntl} from 'react-intl'

interface Props {
  intl?: ReactIntl.InjectedIntl
}

function Greeter ({intl}: Props): JSX.Element {
  <p>{intl.formatMessage({id: 'greetingStringId'})</p>
}

export default injectIntl(Greeter)
```

Now my main question here is: is keeping the `intl` property as optional in the props definition the right thing to do or would there be a more correct way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try using InjectedIntlProps (from react-intl) to add intl to props like this:

```
interface Props {
    foo: any;
}

function Greeter (props: Props & InjectedIntlProps): JSX.Element {
   <p>{props.intl.formatMessage({id: 'greetingStringId'})</p>
}
```

Alternative, extend the interface with InjectedIntlProps:

```
interface Props extends InjectedIntlProps {
    foo: any;
}

function Greeter (props: Props): JSX.Element {
   <p>{props.intl.formatMessage({id: 'greetingStringId'})</p>
}
```